# Change this integral $\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} x \left[ f(x) + f(x+1) \right] dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

It is given that $f(a+b+1 -x) = f(x)$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers then $\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} x \left[ f(x) + f(x+1) \right] dx$ is equal to

1. $\int_{a-1}^{b-1} f(x) dx$
2. $\int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(x+1) dx$
3. $\int_{a-1}^{b-1} f(x+1) dx$
4. $\int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(x) dx$

I tried using integration by parts along with this property $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$ and the one given in the question but I'm unable to get anything. It's that extra $x$ and the fraction $\frac{1}{a+b}$ which is making everything quite uneasy.

Comment: If you are stuck, try using examples. $f$ identically equal to a constant is one such example. Now, compute each of the expressions in the options and the one in the question, and see the matches. This at least helps you eliminate the bad options.

Comment: You can plug in some $f$, say $f(x)=\left(x-\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)^2$ (or even $f(x)=g\left(x-\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)$ for $g(-x)=g(x)$) to see what fits.

Comment: Alexey has a good idea but all the choices are integrals of $f$ over an interval of length $b-a$ so you won't get any extra info by checking constant functions. You can also set $a,b$ to be concrete values. One nice choice is $a=0,b=1$. (yes they said $a$ is positive but who knows why) Makes $1/(a+b)$ disappear and the reflection property of the integral easier to use

Answer (score 1):

Your question is,
$$\dfrac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} x \left[ f(x) + f(x+1) \right] dx$$
Now, in second term i.e. $f(x+1)$, put $x+1$ as $u$ and use $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$ and $f(a+b+1 -x) = f(x)$.

You will get $$\dfrac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} (a+b) \left[ f(x) \right] dx$$. Now substitute $x\rightarrow x+1$, you'll get option 3.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} x \left[ f(x) + f(x+1) \right] dx=I_1+I_2$$
$$I_1=\frac{1}{a+b}\int_{a}^{b}xf(x) dx$$
$$I_2=\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} x f(x+1) dx = \frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a+1}^{b+1} (u-1)f(u) du$$
N0w apply the property:
$$\int_{p}^{q} g(x) dx=\int_{p}^{q} g(p+q-x) dx$$
Then $$I_2=\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a+1}^{b+1} (a+1+b+1-u-1)f(a+b+2-u) du$$
Use $f(a+b+2-u)=f(a+b+1-(u-1))= f(u-1)$. then
$$I_2=\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a+1}^{b+1} (a+b+1-u) f(u-1) du.$$
Let $u-1=w$, then $$I_2=\frac{1}{a+b} \int_{a}^{b} (a+b-w)f(w) dw$$
Finally $$I=I_1+I_2=\int_{a}^{b} f(w) dw =\int_{a-1}^{b-1} f(x+1)dx$$